# What are the differents between microservices and domain driven design?

Tags: node.js, microservices, domain-driven-design

What are the differents between microservices and domain driven design?

Are they the same?

Microservices concept for my best understanding is to keep apart every service that mean build and deploy separately than other services.

ddd is for keep apart every domain (service?) and create Bounded Context between domains I think it's the same as microservices but with difference words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microservices and Domain-driven design are two different things but it comes hand to hand while implementing the microservices.

Domain-driven design is a logical separation of data.

Every microservice always belongs to some domain. Further, it also caters to the sub-domain level.

Benefits of using DDD in microservices architecture:

1)Microservices get separated by domain so it is very easy to maintain.

2)Developing and deploying the microservice will be as per domain.

3)Maintaining config maps for domain and at sub-domain level.

4)Maintaining the code repositories, CI/CD pipeline, and deployment as per domain.

5)Boundary gets defined between microservices for communications.

Comment: I'm confused. because according to video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNFJREcalc0&t=371s  , it say domain contains subdomains and each subdomain is service. correct?

Comment: Yes it’s correct. Take example, on Amazon while shopping you see there are two account one is for billing and other is financial account. So this 2 account belongs to Accountmanagement domain. While deployment you can deploy the whole domain also we can share some common properties across the domain. Even you can deploy the multiple services in one pod but it happens in some cases where one service is act as only a helper service to the other.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone need to clarify domain, subdomain and microservices.
I find it is very helpful

https://microservices.io/patterns/decomposition/decompose-by-subdomain.html

[image]